# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) when installing docker-ce on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I try to prepare Ubuntu 16.04 automatically via script for installing [Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/requirements/), which requires 17.03.2 as latest Docker version:

```
 default: Setting up docker-ce (17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...
    default: Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    default: invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
    default: ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
    default:    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    default:    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-11-13 17:25:47 UTC; 6ms ago
    default:      Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    default:   Process: 4162 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    default:  Main PID: 4162 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Contai....
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial dockerd[4162]: no sockets found via socket act...d
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exite...E
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application....
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered faile....
    default: Nov 13 17:25:47 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result....
    default: Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    default: dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
    default:  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    default: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    default: Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.8) ...
    default: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
    default: Errors were encountered while processing:
    default:  docker-ce
    default: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My script according to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository):

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get remove -y docker docker-engine docker.io

apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

apt-get update
apt-get install -y docker-ce=17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial
```

It seems that Docker itself is working since I can e.g. call `docker --version` after starting the daemon with `service docker start`. But I doesn't know why those errors occurs.

#### Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

   config.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/dependencies.sh"
end
```

I'm using Vagrant with `vagrant up --provision`. Before starting, the old machine was deleted using `vagrant destroy` to make sure that the problems are not caused by some older runs of the script. The version is `16.04.5 LTS`. The `systemctl` and `journalctl` commands gave me a very long output, that doesn't seem to have more information about the problem like

> default: Nov 13 17:41:19 ubuntu-xenial systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Even more strange that I don't get the error when running `vagrant ssh` and executing all the commands hand by hand.